# How to preload next images in Fancybox 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox, fancybox-3

I just started using Fancybox 3.3.5 in my Ruby on Rails project.

As per documentation I use it in a following manner:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-fancybox data-caption="Caption for single image">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

**PROBLEM**: If the original image is very big, loading time (with spinner visible) can take several seconds. I would like to mitigate that.

**MY IDEA**: I imagine the best way to achive that would be to preload (several) following images from the gallery while user is looking at one of them.

**QUESTION**: **Is there a way to preload next images in Fancybox 3?** I know Fancybox doesn't do it out of the box. But maybe you had a similar issue or can provide some hints about doing this in the most efficient way?

I know about the `preload` option provided by Fancybox config. What it does, however, is basically replace the spinner with the thumb version of the image, while loading the original image in the background. This is not what I want, mainly because my thumbs are to small to display them full screen; it just doesn't look good enough.

Answer (score 0):

fancybox automatically loads current and prev/next images.

You can add `data-width` and `data-height` attributes to display thumbnail image while real image is still loading and is slowly appearing over the placeholder, see https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#images for more info.

You can use `data-thumb` attribute to set alternative thumbnail image, see example here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/VyLOJX?editors=1000

If your images are "very big" (like you said), it would not be good idea to try to preload too many of them, because that would slow down everything quite significantly.

Comment: You wrote: "fancybox automatically loads current and prev/next images". Can you point me to the line in source code where it happens? Maybe it would be easy to just "extend" this feature to load more than one next/prev image.

Comment: :D You see, fancybox v3 is more like a slider, therefore prev/next slides are created so that swiping feels much better. If you are really interested, then it is here - https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/blob/master/src/js/core.js#L2381